# Tag search issue in html codes rendered using DangerouslySetInnerHtml

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get data from a service with Axios. Then I take it from the Reducer on the page. I'm inviting the data I've thrown into Redux in a function. I'm parsing a String HTML code with DangerouslySetInnerHtml. And I want to call the h2 tag in the generated html.
With getElementsByTagName I get data in the form of HTMLCollection. But I can't use HTMLCollection in a forEach loop.

```
//code in page 
<div
  className="article-content"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: detail !== undefined && detail.content }}
/>
```

where the function is loaded

```
<div>{this._renderSideBar()}</div>
```

Function

```
var article = document.getElementsByClassName("article-content");
var h2s = article[0]
  .getElementsByClassName("article-detail")[0]
  .getElementsByClassName("article-content")[0]
  .getElementsByTagName("h2");

console.log(h2s) // HTMLCollection 5 result

for(var i = 0; i < h2s.length; i++;){
   // not working
   console.log(h2s[i]);
}
```

I want to set up a loop here but I can't use HTMLCollection as array

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't you use HTMLCollection'? Are you getting any error? What error?

Comment: No error. Never into the for loop @ivp

Comment: Ok.Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works after slight modification. Check below. It iterates through the HTMLCollection and prints the H2s

```js
var article = document.getElementsByClassName("article-content");
var h2s = article[0]
  .getElementsByClassName("article-detail")[0]
  .getElementsByClassName("article-content")[0]
  .getElementsByTagName("h2");

for(var i = 0; i < h2s.length; i++){
   console.log(h2s[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="article-content">
<div class="article-detail">
  <div class="article-content">
    <h2>H2 1</h2>
    <h2>H2 2</h2>
    <h2>H2 3</h2>
    <h2>H2 4</h2>
    <h2>H2 5</h2>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, this work. but i'm rendering with DangerouslySetInnerHtml. so I guess it doesn't work. do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I dont think, it should be a problem. Can you post the HTML here?

Answer (score 0):

convert the nodelist to array with follwing:

```
  var inputList = Array.prototype.slice.call(h2s);
for(var i = 0; i < inputList .length; i++;){
   // not working
   console.log(h2s[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
In function

```
var detailText = this.props.state.blog.detail;
var parser = new DOMParser();
  var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(detailText, "text/html");
  var h2s = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("h2");
  let items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < h2s.length; i++) {
    items.push(h2s[i].innerText);
  }
  return items.map((row, i) => {
    return (
      <li key={i}>
        <a href="#">{row}</a>
      </li>
    );
  });
```